The limit of an integral (under nondominated convergence)
I'd like to compute the following limit
$$\lim_{p\to 0^+}  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi(x)\;\dfrac{x^2-p^2}{(x^2+p^2)^2}\;\textrm{d}x$$
in terms of $\varphi$, where $\varphi$ is a positive, smooth, rapidly decreasing ($\forall n,|x|^n\!\varphi(x)\to0\;\;\textrm{for}\; |x|\to\infty$) function on the real line.
Notice that the hypotheses of the dominated convergence theorem are not satisfied: indeed, the integrand converges pointwise to the nonintegrable function $\varphi(x)/x^2$ (If the convergence was dominated, the pointwise limit would have to be in $L^1$).
(If it's of any help, notice that
$$\dfrac{x^2-p^2}{(x^2+p^2)^2}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial p}\left(\dfrac{p}{x^2+p^2}\right)$$
and $p/(x^2+p^2)$ tends to $\pi\cdot\delta_0$ in the sense of distributions.)
Maybe this can't be done at this level of generality.
--
P.S. I'm asking this in behalf of a physicist that is not on the SE websites. The actual $\varphi$ in their research problem is an explicit function which is itself an integral of a complicated elementary function of two variables.

I can’t work out the details right now, but here’s what Id try: split the integral into two pieces, one where $|x|<1$ and $|x|\geq 1$. For the second piece, you can use dominated convergence to push the limit in. For the first term, write $\phi(x)=\phi(0)+\phi’(0) x + \epsilon(x)$. For the remainder term, you can again push the limit inside by dominated convergence (so now you have some “regularized functional” of $\phi$). All that remains is the two terms of the Taylor expansion. This is an integral of rational functions, so you can figure out exactly how badly the terms diverge as $p\to 0$.

For a "good" function $\varphi(x)$, integrating by parts a couple of times
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi(x)\frac{x^2-p^2}{(x^2+p^2)^2}dx=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi(x),d\left(\frac x{x^2+p^2}\right)=-\varphi(x)\frac x{x^2+p^2}\bigg|{-\infty}^\infty+\int{-\infty}^\infty \frac {x,\varphi'(x)}{x^2+p^2}dx$$
$$=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi'(x),d\left(\ln(x^2+p^2)\right)=-\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi''(x)\ln(x^2+p^2)dx\to-\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi''(x)\ln(x^2)dx$$

If the function does not have a continuous derivative at $x=0$ (for example, $\varphi(x)=e^{-|x|}$), you split the interval: $(-\infty;0];[0;\infty)$. In this case the divergent (with respect to $p$) term appears:
$$I=\ln(p)\Big(\varphi'(0^-)-\varphi'(0^+)\Big)+O(1)$$

@Svyatoslav: This certainly solves the problem - thank you. I had tried integrating by parts one time but (silly me) not twice! :)
